# Anyone help me to add an image size in this code?

Tags: php, html, image

I have the following code :

`<?php echo "<img src=\"".$d['pic_post']."\"><br>";  ?>`

I want to change the image size by adding this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<img src=\"".$d['pic_post']." width=""100" "\"><br>";                 
?>
```

But it isn't working. Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: You have 2 double quotes. Try changing `src=\"".` to `src=\".`

Comment: <?php echo '<img src="'.$d['pic_post'].'" width="100"><br>';  ?>

Comment: @Cattla thanks so much it's successfully work!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
 echo "<img src='".$d['pic_post']."' width='100'><br>";                 
?>
```

With CSS would be:

```
<?php
 echo "<img src='".$d['pic_post']."' style='width:100px'><br>";                 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `inline styles`.

Do:

```
<?php
    echo "<img src='".$d['pic_post']."' style='width:100px;' \/><br>";
?>
```

[Learn more.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Here is an **example working code snippet**:

```html
<img src='http://gcmaz.com/wp-content/gallery/test/sample1-c78a690251ae02408f6e58ffe8ce054b6bb53302.jpg' style='width:100px;'>
```

Note that the height will be automatically adjusted as per the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
<?php
 echo "<img src='".$d['pic_post']."' style="width:100px"/><br>";          
?>
```